# Spresense SDK: nuttxリンク時に section `.bss' will not fit in region `ram'エラーで失敗する

Tags: spresense

`myapp`プロジェクトを[ここ](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/nuttx-developer-guide#_spresense_sdk%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E6%89%80%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2)を参考に追加して`nuttx`をビルドしました。最後のリンク時に以下のようなエラーが出ます。
どうもRAMサイズオーバーと言っているようですが、わたしはてっきりFlash8MBにfirmwareは書き込まれると思っていました。回避方法はありますか？

Spresense-nuttx: v1.5.0
Spresense SDK: v1.5.0
Host OS: WSL1.0 on Windows10
Toolchain: arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2018-q2-update) 7.3.1 20180622 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 261907]

エラー個所のみ抜粋:

```
echo "LD: nuttx"
LD: nuttx
arm-none-eabi-ld --entry=__start -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -g -Map=/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/nuttx.map --cref --defsym __stack=_vectors+1572864 -T/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp/scripts/ramconfig.ld -L"/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/lib" -L"/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp/board"  \
        -o "/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/nuttx"   \
        --start-group -lbsp -lsystem -lextdrivers -lexamples -lmyapps -lsched -ldrivers -lconfigs -lc -lmm -larch -lcxx -lapps -lnet -lfs -lbinfmt -lgraphics -lnx -lcxx -lboard "/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libm.a"  "/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/thumb/v7e-m/fpv4-sp/hard/libgcc.a" --end-group
arm-none-eabi-ld: /home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/nuttx section `.bss' will not fit in region `ram'
arm-none-eabi-ld: region `ram' overflowed by 31052 bytes
Makefile:188: recipe for target 'nuttx' failed
make[1]: *** [nuttx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/norio/ws/firmware/spresense/sdk/bsp'
Makefile:182: recipe for target 'nuttx' failed
make: *** [nuttx] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

google翻訳
セクション `.bss 'は領域` ram'に適合しません

bssというセクションは初期化しない変数が配置されるセクションです
おそらく、これらの変数エリアが肥大化して、RAMのエリアを超えてしまったんでしょう。
これらのサイズを縮小するか、セクションの配置／割当を変えて、超えないようにする必要があります。

Flashメモリは、特別の手順でしか書き換えることができないメモリです。
変数はこのエリアには配置できません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードを削減することで`.bss`は解消しました。ただ、慢性的にメモリが不足しているので対策を探しています。Flash8Mがあると思いますが、活用することはできないのでしょうか。```NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-7.22
nsh> sercon
sercon: Registering CDC/ACM serial driver
sercon: Successfully registered the CDC/ACM serial driver
nsh> free
             total       used       free    largest
Mem:        495136      80736     414400     408080```